# BTS6163D Struggles to turn on LEDs with long cable

Tags: power, led, mosfet, current, dc

I have a circuit that turns on and off LED's utilizing BTS6163D ProFET's for overcurrent protection and open circuit detection. So far it seemed to be working without any issues until I tried a different type of light.

For some reason these new lights struggle to turn on, there is an oscillation at around 1.26khz from about 4.4v to 27v (lights are powered with 26v) measured at the output of the BTS6163D. If the light is manually disconnected and reconnected to the BTS6163D without disabling the input pin, the oscillation goes away. If the BTS6163D cycled off and back on via the input pin the oscillation comes back. Shortening the cable between the light and the BTS6163D lessens or even removes the oscillation which leads me to believe this has something to do with induction caused by turning on the light over the long cable.

Is it possible the BTS6163D is shutting down from a false short circuit detection? If that is the case, why is it coming back right away, shouldn't it latch off?

Upon further inspection, the old lights show maybe 1-3 oscillations before fully turning on, however, they always fully turn on no matter the cable length. The old lights pulled around 500mA and the new ones are about 400mA, could this make that big of a difference?

The cable is 14 gauge around 50-100ft.

I am really at a loss here, I already have multiple boards manufactured and would rather not have to scrap them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please see the datasheet and scope images below.

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS6163D-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625a888733015aa3da01a1101e

Voltage measured at the output of BTS6163D.
[image: Voltage measured at the output of BTS6163D]

Yellow is the voltage at the output of BTS6163D and purple is at the light.
[image: Yellow is the voltage at the output of BTS6163D and purple is at the light]

This is the original light.
[image: This is the original light]